# Proving the following moment distribution function.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I am trying to prove the following relation , 
If $u \in L^p(\Omega)$ $\Omega \subset R^n $and $0 < p <\infty$ , the the following relation is valid , 
$$\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}^p = p\int_0^\infty t^{p-1} d_u(t)dt$$ where $d_u(t) $ is a distribution function defined by $\mu (L^n(x\in \Omega : |u(x)| >t))$

How do i go about proving the above relation. Can you give me some suggestions.
Thanks . 
here is my solution , but i am not fully satisfied because i cannot argue some of the steps that i have done myself : 
$$\int_0^\infty t^{p-1}d_u(t) d(t)= \int_0^\infty t^{p-1}  L^n\{x\in \Omega : |u(x)| >t\}dt $$
$$=\int_0^\infty t^{p-1 } \int_{\{x:|u(x)| > t \}} 1.dL^n(x) dt$$
$$=\int_0^\infty \int_{\{x:|u(x)| > t \}} t^{p-1}.dL^n(x) dt $$

Now  i know here i have to use fubini , but i am not able to argue myself satisfactorily why ?

$$=\int_{\{x:|u(x)| > t \}}\int_0^t t^{p-1}.dt dL^n(x)$$ (am i allowed to do this here ? if yes why if not why not please )
$$=\int_\Omega |u(x)|^p.dL^n(x) dt$$ , in this step also i am not very clear . I am not satisfied much although i kind of got the solution :( Thank you for your explanation. Please do comment and help me .

Comment: There should be a $t$ outside the integral. Hint: Fubini's theorem.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo : Thanks , i think i got it . will get back if i have some doubts.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo : I have done the problem but i am not satisfied myself with my own solution, because i am not able to argue myself why i did so . Can you see and give me some explanation. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the step where *i am not able to argue myself satisfactorily why* by
$$
p\int_0^\infty \int_{\{x:|u(x)| > t \}} t^{p-1}\mathrm dL^n(x) \mathrm dt
=
\int_X\int_0^{|u(x)|} pt^{p-1}\mathrm dt\mathrm dL^n(x) 
=
\int_X|u(x)|^{p}\mathrm dL^n(x).
$$

Comment: I am still not satisfied with my understanding about how u did the first step ie change of limits of integration.

Comment: Tonelli for the integral of the function $(x,t)\mapsto pt^{p-1}\mathbf 1_{|u(x)|\gt t}$ with respect to the measure $L^n\otimes\mathrm{Leb}$ on $X\times(0,+\infty)$.